# Number of paths in a graph with minimum length

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have $ n $ points and I am trying to figure out in how many ways we can create a path.Path must connect all $n$ points and the length should be equal to $n-1$ .Shouldn't the answer be -$ n*(n-1)..*1=n! $ .Because we choose consequtively?

Comment: Does the order of the path matter; for instance is 1 -> 2 -> 3 the same path as 3 -> 2 -> 1?

Comment: No it doesnt matter

Comment: Try your formula with $n=2$ and see if you can think how it needs to be modified.

Comment: n! /2? I guess is it?

Comment: Yup! Can you modify the argument from your original post to prove this?